# write a program to get response, request from web method calls

Tags: c#, web-services

I need to write a small C# Win32 program that can show me like a log file the response and request that is done when we call a web method of a third party web service that is also in .NET But I have no idea where to start from or what sample codes to look at.
So There is a third party application we are using that is using its own ASP.net web service to do some stuff, so it has some methods like GetDevice, GetPatient, etc that we are calling, now I want my program to show me like a log file what is going on with response/request when I am call each of those methods.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Have tried looking at [WireShark?](http://www.wireshark.org/)

> Wireshark is the world's foremost network protocol analyzer. It lets
>   you capture and interactively browse the traffic running on a computer
>   network.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out. But for some reasons like this is a domain for one of our clients that I cannot connect to, running our app on citrix, etc.. and their sys admin limitations I just cannot install anything on their machine, so we have to write a small progream and give it to them, tell them run this and send us the log file so we can look at it in house, so I have to write something myself I think ..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using HTTP protocol, you can configure your client to go thru a Web Debugging Proxy like Fiddler. Fiddler can be downloaded free from [www.fiddler2.com](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Comment: Thanks,it is HTTP But for some reasons like this is a domain for one of our clients that I cannot connect to, running our app on citrix, etc.. and their sys admin limitations I just cannot install anything on their machine, so we have to write a small progream and give it to them, tell them run this and send us the log file so we can look at it in house, so I have to write something myself I think ..